# Prove that for any real number $y > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y < 10^{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to finish this problem. I approached this problem with a proof by contradiction:

```
    Let $A = \{10^{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and suppose that A is bounded above by $y$ (so $y$ is an upper bound for the set $A = \{10^{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\})$. \\
    Let $\alpha =$ lub $A$. (we can say this because of the completeness axiom) \\

    (Completeness axiom: every nonempty subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above has a least upper bound (i.e., lub(A) exists and $\in \mathbb{R})$. \\

    Let $y = 1 > 0$. So $\alpha < \alpha + 1$. \\
    So $\alpha - 1 < \alpha$. \\
    Since $\alpha$ is the lub(A), $\alpha - 1$ cannot be an upper bound for A. \\
    So $\alpha - 1 < 10^{n + 1}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
```

I think I should now prove that alpha - 1 < 10^(n + 1) but I don't know if I'm on the right track with this proof?

Comment: Use the fact that log is defined on this domain and is monotonic then read about Archimedes's property.

Comment: $\alpha - 1 < 10^{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Then $10^{n+1} \le \alpha < 10^{n}+1$. Then we just need to show $10^{n+1} < 10^n+1$ is a contradiction.

Comment: "I think I should now prove that alpha - 1 < 10^(n + 1)"  You already have proven that. Now what you must prove is that $10^{n+2} > \alpha$ which would be a contradiction.

Comment: "Let $y = 1 > 0$." Don't bother with this.  $1 < 10^1<y$ so we *know* this is not true.  ANd that has *nothing* to do with $\alpha < \alpha + 1$.  $c < c+ 1$ for *every* $c$ (because $0 < 1$ so $c +0 < c + 1$) and likewis $\alpha-1 < \alpha$ always. YOu *don't* need to show those.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just prove it this way: Let $M$ be the number of digits $\lceil y \rceil \ge y$ has written out base 10. Then $10^{M+1}$ has $M+2$ digits so $y \le \lceil y\rceil < 10^{M+1}$.

Comment: Mr stakexchange is supposed to use only things previously proved in his textbook.  Unfortunately, that may not include things in this argument.  Doubly unfortunately, those of us here do not know what was in that textbook.

Comment: This assumes 1) that there is an integer that is larger than $y$ and 2) that all integers have a finite number of digits and that 3) all integers can by written in base $10$ by a number of digits.   None of those things can be assumed as a given.  In particular 3) *assumes* that *exactly* what you are trying to prove.

Comment: I would wager the entire *reason* the OP is trying to prove this statement is as a stepping stone toward proving that we can express all real numbers in decimals.  The *very* first step in expressing $y$ as a decimal is to find the $n$ so that $10^n \le y < 10^{n+1}$.  If you don't know there *is* such an $n$ you can't know that you *can* express $y$ as a decimal.

Comment: tl;dr.  This proof is circular in it assumes what needs to be proven.

Answer (score 1):

Supose that $S=\{10^{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded above and let $A$ be the supremum of $S$. Note that $\forall n\in \mathbb N\quad10^{n+1}\le A$ (becuase $n+1$ is a natural), then $\forall n\in \mathbb N\quad10^{n}\le\frac{A}{10}$, thus $\frac{A}{10}$ is a upper bound less than $A$, but this contradicts the definition of $A$, so $S$ is not bounded.

Comment: Nitpick.  If $A$ is the supremum then for all any natural $kootchiekootchie$ we have $10^{kootchikoochie} \le A$ (not necessarily *strictly* less than) But for any $n\in \mathbb N$ then $10^{n+1}\le A$ so $10^n < A$ (and as that is true for all $n$ it *is* true for $n+1$.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of concepts.

The set $S=\{1,10,100,.....\}=\{10^n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$.

$S$ is not empty.  Either it is bounded above or it is not.

Now If there is no $n$ so that $y < 10^n$ then $y \ge 10^n$ for all $n$ and therefore $y$ is an upper bound of $S$ and $S$ *is* bounded above.

The reals have the least upper bound property so if $S$ is bounded above there is a least upper bound of $S$ or $\sup S$.  But that means that $\sup S -1$ is *not* an upper bound which means there is an element of $S$, a $10^n$ so that $\sup S- 1 < 10^n \le \sup S$.

Which means further than $\sup S - 1 < 10^n < 10^{n+1} \le \sup S$ and so $10^{n+1}- 10^n < 1$ which.... just isn't possible.  (It would mean that $9=10-1 < \frac 1{10^n} < 1$ and that's just plain nutty.)

So $S$ can't be bounded above and $y$ can't be an upper bound of $S$ so there must be a $10^n \in S$ so that $10^n > y$.

Answer (score 0):

OK the number $10$ can be replaced by any number greater than $1$.

Also it is better to use Archimedean principle directly instead of supremum principle. Note that an argument similar to the one in your approach is used to prove Archimedean principle.

Use the fact that $$10^{n}=(1+9)^n\geq 1+9n$$ (via binomial theorem). Given $y>0$ we have  by Archimedean principle an $n\in\mathbb {N} $ such that $n>\dfrac{y-1}{9}$ or $9n+1>y$ and hence $10^n>y$.